# Any way to reduce BH R package size for a specific project?

Tags: c++, r, compilation

The BH R package is very big (1.3G).  This causes some issues on systems with limited space.  Is there a way to select a reduced set of package components that are minimally required for compiling R packages that depend on BH?

Comment: Build the packages on another system and transfer the binary packages?

Comment: Is it a package you are developing yourself that depends on BH? If so, you can include the needed headers from Boost in your package. Boost has tools to detect which headers are used by your project.

Comment: @janvanderlaan : but not for UNIX, right?

Comment: @tim You mean building binary packages or the boost tools (which is `bcp` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html by then way). Both can be done on unix.